# Is it sufficient to load the Native library at only one activity while we need to use it inside whole Android app?

Tags: android, android-studio, java-native-interface, jnienv

I want to use Native JNI library inside my android project. But I've a question, like I want to use this library methods inside around 10 activities of my app. So should I load the library to every activity or just loading on Splash Activity is sufficient. Also, how to handle it inside fragment, like will it occur any problem if the activity pauses or resume etc. I'm confused, please help a beginner. 
Thanks is advanced :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni):

> If you have only one class with native methods, it makes sense for the call to System.loadLibrary to be in a static initializer for that class. Otherwise you might want to make the call from Application so you know that the library is always loaded, and always loaded early.

So there are two ways to load your library and no need to load it inside each your activity, i would prefer the first way because it's more clean and compact.

As for influence of the activity lifecycle on your native library -
if you don't call some library methods inside your activity's or fragment's lifecycle methods so your library will work as usual until your app is terminated.